# Facebook Submit for Login Review but still in Development Mode

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post to Instagram from within my app. My Facebook Dev app is in Development mode:

[image]

I can log in to Facebook and post/share to Facebook Pages, Groups and profiles from within my app so happy with that. I am now trying to post/share to Instagram so I am calling the FB.login as follows:

[image]

Where the method `PostToInstagram()` ultimately is doing this:

[image]

However when I attempt to call this, I get the FB Login popup, I click to post but I keep getting the error:

```
(#10) Application does not have permission for this action
```

On the popup, I have the option to change the FB/Instagram settings, when I try saving inside here I see:

[image]

I would have thought I would be okay as I am still in development mode. My other calls to FB api work fine. Could I be missing any scopes? Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Posting to a group, requires the app to be "installed" in that group first. And from all I have read so far, you can't do that, while the app is still in development mode, because apparently the UI where the group admin can find apps to add to their group, won't list it while still in dev mode.

Comment: Sorry, I am all quite new to this.. But what 'Group' is this referring to? Facebook, Instagram? I have a Facebook 'Page' linked to my Instagram Business account? Does it mean the FB Page?

Comment: Sorry, I realise that this is more to do with what I have typed in my error. The first part of the error Post to MyGroup unsuccessful) is hard coded. This is not actuall posting to a group. I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was talking about posting to an FB group. For IG Contentz Publishing, there are quite a few limitations & requirements listed on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing, I guess you have to check against that to figure out what might be missing.

Comment: Thanks for that... I had seen that list of limitations so tried to work within that. I have since found that according to this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed you can only publish from Android or IOS app but cannot spy any support to publish via Javascript. :(

Comment: These are different things. Sharing means to provide your app users with a way to share your content to their IG user profile - that requires user interaction, the user is presented with a dialog from where they can actively trigger the share. The Content Publishing API is to make posts to Instagram Business IG User accounts, from a backend.

Comment: Yeah, sharing to an IG profile is what I 'really' want to be able to do but couldn't find anything on how to do it in Javascript so ended up looking to see if I could post to a business account from my app instead (which is where I was when I posted this question here).  I may post a separate question on here about being able to Share to an IG profile from my app using Javascript, however I think it is just possible from Android and IOS apps :(